# How to automatically link specific words in a node to other nodes?

Tags: navigation, nodes

Lets say i have a node with a body like:

"
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc cursus dapibus diam sit amet aliquet.
"

I'm looking for a way to convert the **consectetur** (for example) word into a link to another node, when the node is displayed (**and not when is edited!**)

What is the best practices to define what node shuld be linked to that word (taxonomy? cck field?), and how to do that (theme_preprocess_node?).

Please note that, whatever hook/theme function i can use, the results **must** be cached (until the node get edited again): the site is for a no-profit cultural association with the lowest budget i've ever seen ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the [Glossary](http://drupal.org/project/glossary) module does what you need?

You define a taxonomy and it will scan the text and provide links to the terms when a node is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely use taxonomy for the relation between node and word, I would then use hook_node_save to alter the value of the body and add the links with a preg_replace. By adding a specific class to those links you can then remove those links with hook_form_alter before the body field is displayed for editing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a Drupal 7 alternative, then the [Glossify](https://www.drupal.org/project/glossify) module is the way to go for this.